# jupyter nbextension: Install javascript and css files failed

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, miniconda, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I tried to install the *javascript and the css files* to finalise my jupyter notebook nbextension installation process as is written [here](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html). When I enter the command `jupyter contrib nbextension install --sys-prefix` in my jupyter notebook was started from conda, it fails and returns:

```
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (hu_HU.UTF-8)
[W 17:49:28 InstallContribNbextensionsApp] Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `InstallContribNbextensionsApp`.
[I 17:49:28 InstallContribNbextensionsApp] jupyter contrib nbextension install --sys-prefix
[I 17:49:28 InstallContribNbextensionsApp] Installing jupyter_contrib_nbextensions nbextension files to jupyter data directory
[I 17:49:28 InstallContribNbextensionsApp] Installing /home/mathegergely/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/runtools -> runtools
[I 17:49:28 InstallContribNbextensionsApp] Up to date: /home/mathegergely/miniconda3/share/jupyter/nbextensions/runtools/demo.gif
[I 17:49:28 InstallContribNbextensionsApp] Up to date: /home/mathegergely/miniconda3/share/jupyter/nbextensions/runtools/runtools_nb.png
[I 17:49:28 InstallContribNbextensionsApp] Copying: /home/mathegergely/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/runtools/gutter.css -> /home/mathegergely/miniconda3/share/jupyter/nbextensions/runtools/gutter.css
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mathegergely/miniconda3/bin/jupyter-contrib", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/mathegergely/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 254, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mathegergely/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/mathegergely/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_contrib_core/application.py", line 50, in start
    super(JupyterContribApp, self).start()
  File "/home/mathegergely/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 243, in start
    self.subapp.start()
  File "/home/mathegergely/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/application.py", line 231, in start
    super(ContribNbextensionsApp, self).start()
  File "/home/mathegergely/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 243, in start
    self.subapp.start()
  File "/home/mathegergely/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/application.py", line 178, in start
    toggle_install_files(self._toggle_value, **kwargs_files)
  File "/home/mathegergely/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/install.py", line 74, in toggle_install_files
    nbextensions.install_nbextension_python(
  File "/home/mathegergely/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 217, in install_nbextension_python
    full_dest = install_nbextension(
  File "/home/mathegergely/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 191, in install_nbextension
    _maybe_copy(src, dest_file, logger=logger)
  File "/home/mathegergely/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 1041, in _maybe_copy
    shutil.copy2(src, dest)
  File "/home/mathegergely/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 433, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/home/mathegergely/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 376, in copystat
    _copyxattr(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow)
  File "/home/mathegergely/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 326, in _copyxattr
    os.setxattr(dst, name, value, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/home/mathegergely/miniconda3/share/jupyter/nbextensions/runtools/gutter.css'
```

Could somebody points me in the right direction?! Actually I do not understand the error message generated.

Thanks for your help in advance!